# How to put several plots in a subplot matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having some issues putting several plots in a subplot matrix.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create features dataset
X = pd.DataFrame(columns=["feature1", "feature2"], 
                  data=[["A", "m"],
                        ["A", "m"],
                        ["A", "m"],
                        ["A", "m"],
                        ["A", "f"],
                        ["A", "f"],                         
                        ["B", "f"],
                        ["B", "f"],
                        ["B", "f"],
                        ["B", "x"],
                        ["B", "x"]])

# Create target dataset
target = pd.DataFrame(columns=["target"], 
                  data=[[0],
                        [0],
                        [0],
                        [1],
                        [1],
                        [1],                         
                        [1],
                        [1],
                        [0],
                        [0],
                        [0]])

plt.figure()
for i, feature_name in enumerate(X.columns):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)   #  2 by 2 subplot matrix
    df = pd.concat((X[[feature_name]], target), axis=1)
    df['counts'] = 1
    df_percentage = df.groupby([feature_name, 'target']).count()/df[[feature_name, 'counts']].groupby([feature_name]).count()*100   # calculate percentage
    df_percentage.reset_index(level=[feature_name, 'target']).pivot(index=feature_name, columns='target', values="counts").plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)   # plot stacked bar chart for each feature
    plt.ylabel('Percentage')
    plt.legend(['Target = 0', 'Target = 1'], loc='upper right')
    plt.tight_layout()
```

I am trying to plot the 2 bar charts in a 2 by 2 subplot matrix. The bar chart output is really weird and it's not displaying properly. It displays 2 empty plots followed by the bar chart for "feature2" one on top of another.

I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: a 2x2 subplot grid has 4 subplots. You have only have 2 bar charts. Presumably you want just a 1x2 grid - try changing to `plt.subplot(1, 2, i+1)`

Comment: Thanks @tmdavison, I don't believe this is the case. Anyhow, I have tried changing it to `plt.subplot(1, 2, i+1)` but it is still not displaying properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have somehow figured this out:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for i, feature_name in enumerate(df_X_train[['ps_ind_01', 'ps_ind_02_cat', 'ps_ind_03', 'ps_ind_04_cat']].select_dtypes(include=['category']).columns):
    locals()['a'+str(i+1)] = plt.subplot(2, 3, i+1)
    df = pd.concat((df_X_train[[feature_name]], df_y_train), axis=1)
    df['counts'] = 1
    df_percentage = df.groupby([feature_name, 'target']).count()/df[[feature_name, 'counts']].groupby([feature_name]).count()*100
    df_percentage.reset_index(level=[feature_name, 'target']).pivot(index=feature_name, columns='target', values="counts").plot.bar(ax=locals()['a'+str(i+1)] , stacked=True, rot=0)       
    plt.ylabel('Percentage')
    plt.legend(['0', '1'], title='target', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()
```